# how to point text around equations with arrow marks dimensional

Tags: tikz-pgf, amsmath, mathdesign

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[T1,mtbold]{mathtime}
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\definecolor{voilet}{cmyk}{.69,.93,0,0}
\begin{equation}
\tikzmarknode{t}{\mathrm{t_c}}=0.01378\left(\frac{\mathrm{\tikzmarknode{L}{L}_w\tikzmarknode{r}{r}_{ke}}}{\mathrm{{S}_w^{0.5}\tikzmarknode{w}{}}}\right)
\end{equation}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,voilet,>=Stealth,node distance=1cm,font=\scriptsize]
  \draw[Latex-] (t) -- ++ (-1,0) node[left,minimum size=.5cm] {\small{time of}\\ {concentration [hr]}};
  \draw[Latex-] (L) -- ++ (0,1) node[align=left]{\small watershed length [ft]};
  \draw[Latex-] (r) -- ++ (0,1) node[align=right] {\small Kerby coefficient [-] (Table 3-3)};
  \draw[Latex-] (w.south west) -- ++ (0,-1) node[right,xshift=3pt] {\small watershed slope [ft ft$^{-1}$]};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Required outputs:

[image: equation around text with arrows]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

For writing multi line text in node you need to add into node style `align=center` and/or define `text width=...` of node:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[T1,mtbold]{mathtime}
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                tikzmark}
\definecolor{voilet}{cmyk}{.69,.93,0,0}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]

\begin{equation}
\tikzmarknode{t}{\mathrm{t_c}}=0.01378\left(\frac{\mathrm{\tikzmarknode{L}{L}_w\tikzmarknode{r}{r}_{ke}}}{\mathrm{{S}_w^{0.5}\tikzmarknode{w}{}}}\right)
\end{equation}
~\\
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,
    color=voilet,
    >=Stealth,
    node distance=1cm, 
    lbl/.style = {align=center, font=\small}  % <--- new
                        ]
\draw[<-] (t) -- ++ (-0.5,0)    node[lbl,left]        {time of\\ concentration [hr]}; % <--- now the text is in two lines
\draw[<-] (L) -- ++ (-0.5,0.5)  node[lbl,above left]  {watershed length [ft]}; % node position is moved to left
\draw[<-] (r) -- ++ ( 0.5,0.5)  node[lbl,above right] {Kerby coefficient\\ {[-]} (Table 3-3)};% node position is moved to right
\draw[<-] (w.south west) -- ++ (0.5,-0.5)
                                node[lbl,right]       {watershed slope\\ {[ft ft$^{-1}$]}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\lipsum[12]
\end{document}
```

*Note:*

- square bracket in node's text, which follows to `\\` had to be encapsulated in curly braces.
- `tikzpicture` require additional vertical space, which we had to add before and after equation (before: empty line + `\vspace{2\baselineskip}`, after: empty line). Otherwise labels written by `tikzpicture` will intrude in the text above and below equation.